# Uploading pictures to Twitter from android with Twitter4j

Tags: android, twitter, media, twitter4j, tweets

Is there any way to call the Twitter API *update_with_media* POST method to upload photos by using Twitter4j? I mean, without using a middle service as TwitPic or YFrog?

If it is not possible, what is the best way to post tweets with pictures from an android native app? Could anybody tell me about a working example for android apps?

Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            mImageUri = data.getData(); 
            mPath = getRealPathFromURI(mImageUri); //from Gallery 

            if (mPath == null)
                mPath = mImageUri.getPath(); //from File Manager

            if (mPath != null) 
                bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPath);
        } else {
            mPath   = mImageUri.getPath();
            bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPath);
        }
Authorization auth=twitter.getAuthorization();
            ImageUpload uploadPhoto=ImageUpload.getTwitpicUploader(TwitPic_api_Key, (OAuthAuthorization) auth);
            Log.d(TAG, "Start sending image...");

            try {
                url = uploadPhoto.upload(new File(mPath));
                result = 1;
                Log.d(TAG, "Image uploaded, Twitpic url is " + url);            
            } catch (Exception e) {        
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to send image");

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```